# transformation from Java application to Java app (NetBeans)

Tags: java, web-applications, netbeans

I have finished a java application in NetBeans (made of single jFrame form), but was at the very end instructed, to transform it an app. I did so by adding a new jApplet form to the same project and copied all of the contents from jFrame form, onto a new jApplet form, and it runs perfectly from Netbeans. However, when i try to run the app.class from the HTML document in the browser, it doesn't run and displays the following error:

[image]

HTML file (positioned in the same folder as NewJApplet.class(..Gume\build\classes\demo)) contains:

```
<applet code="NewJApplet.class" height=800 width=600></applet>
```

Project structure:

[image]

I tried running the automatically generated html file, but it displays just a gray area.
Please help me solve the problem, i'm really short on time. Thank you.

Comment: I think code="NewJApplet.class" should be code="demo.NewJApplet.class" or code="demo.NewJApplet"

Comment: I tried both, still doesn't work

Comment: Then the html file needs to be moved up above the demo directory

Comment: maybe my answer here [Applet calling with html](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23460921/1322642) can help you?