# Applet class not found NetBeans

Tags: java, netbeans, applet

I am new at applets and Netbeans.

I tried to run an applet from an HTML file but it gives me this error message :

[image: Applet Not Found Error Message]

This is the architecture I made for the project :

[image: Project Architecture]

As you can see in line 15, the code I used for calling the applet is :

`<applet codebase="classes" code="com/gephi/test/AppletTest.class" width="500" height="500" ></applet>`

I googled a little bit and I have found some suggestions saying that I should call the jar file corresponding to the class.

I am new at NetBeans so can you please tell me where I can find ".jar" and ".class" files?

Thanks!

Comment: look at my answer here [call applet](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23460921/1322642). May be it can help you.

Answer (score 1):

When you are writing the `<applet>` tag then in this you don't need to write `.class` with the class name.

Just write,

`code="com/gephi/test/AppletTest"`

EDIT

What one more thing you can try is, try writing,

`code="com/gephi/test/AppletTest.java"`

or better

`code="com.gephi.test.AppletTest"`

Comment: Thanks bro, but the problem is still there!
I still have the same error message!

Comment: @user1885868  What you are trying to do is, creating an HTML page in Desktop application, I am not sure if it will work. Why don't you try it with a web application? I believe that will be a better option. Check this link https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/web/applets.html

Comment: Thanks @GPRathour that tuto was helpful!